# How to convert IQueryable<T> collection to IMongoQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mocking

I need to create a MongoDB repository mock. There is a method that returns a `IMongoQueryable<T>` in my repository. I don't know how to create an object that implemented this interface.

I really need just this method mocked. I looked at the `IMongoQueryable` and I was able to see there is a `IQueryable` interface, look:

```
public interface IMongoQueryable<T> : IMongoQueryable, IQueryable<T>, IAsyncCursorSource<T>
```

I thought that I may create a MongoDB collection base on list of object, however I didn't to create an instance of this too. If I create an instance of `MongoCollection`, maybe I invoke `AsQueryable` method to return `IMongoQueryable` object.

Does anyone have an idea to do this?

Answer (score 2):

When I run in to this problem I just turn on strict mocking for Moq then I just keep running the test mocking out methods till it stops throwing exceptions about the interface.

```
var mock = new Mock<IMongoQueryable<Foo>>(MockBehavior.Strict);

//add setup here as you run in to exceptions.

var mockInstance = mock.Object;
```

Comment: I have a collection that I'd like to use in some queries, because they are very complex. In this case, how can setup the return that collection?

Answer (score 2):

you are right. You need to call `AsQueryable` but one from namespace: `MongoDB.Driver.Linq.`

To access it write:

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

PS be very careful if you use `System.Linq` in that same file. You will have extension method conflicts.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement a solution, however I didn't.

```
var dataQueryable = data.AsQueryable();
        _mongoQueryableMock = new Mock<IMongoQueryable<T>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        _mongoQueryableMock.Setup(r => r.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());
        _mongoQueryableMock.Setup(r => r.Provider).Returns(dataQueryable.Provider);
        _mongoQueryableMock.Setup(r => r.ElementType).Returns(dataQueryable.ElementType);
        _mongoQueryableMock.Setup(r => r.Expression).Returns(dataQueryable.Expression);
```

I converted my list to queryable anf after that setup this list to mock. But when wuery is performed there isn't any data.

What may be wrong